# Dapper row to json

Tags: c#, .net, json, dapper

**Question**

We have a Dapper Row as a result from a Dapper Query, which I want to store as a json string in our database. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get that to work.
So, let's start with some background information.

**Background info**

We're doing a project where we extract *Table Names* from a table, to know which tables we have to address. We also want this to be as flexible as possible, so we decided to not use a particular POCO for our data.

We're using SQL Server 2014, so unfortunately we don't have the option 'FOR JSON' yet.

**Code**

Our code looks something like this, where GetData is our actual query:

```
var data = _queryHandler.Handle(new GetData(tableName.ToString(), 0), database);
```

The Handle technically just connects to the Database, calling

```
conn.QueryAsync(query, parameters)
```

GetData looks like this (simplified):

```
EXEC ('SELECT * FROM ' + @table + ')'
```

**Reasoning**

Because the table name differs each time, we don't want to force a POCO on the output. Sometimes it's a user, other times a role, so to say, so there's no prediction what output it returns.

**Results**

This works fine. We can extract the data in our variable and this looks like it's an IEnumerable, which should be fine. I gather we can just read them in a loop and extract the rows. So far, no problem.

**The issue at hand**

Next thing we want to do is to convert the data from said DapperRow to a json string, but I cannot seem to get the data to behave like a json string as  JsonConvert.SerializeObject fails miserably. The DapperRow looks like this (again, simplified).

```
{{DapperRow, Id = '07501399-b385-4d8e-bacc-gad9d04c35f7', UserName = 'test8', ApplicationId = '4721fafb-12e6-4e3c-9298-etd82d18a0cb', IsApproved = 'True', IsLockedOut = 'False', CreateDate = '26-3-2019 07:52:55' }}
```

I've already looked into things like the `SqlMapper.ITypeHandler`, but I'm still not getting there. For instance with the TypeHandler, I get stuck on the destinationType as I don't want a particular type - well, except for a json object. But that's not an accepted type.

```
public class JsonObjectTypeHandler : SqlMapper.ITypeHandler
{
    public void SetValue(IDbDataParameter parameter, object value)
    {
        parameter.Value = (value == null)
            ? (object)DBNull.Value
            : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        parameter.DbType = DbType.String;
    }

    public object Parse(Type destinationType, object value)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(value.ToString(), destinationType);
    }
}
```

The only other thing that crosses my mind is to extract each and every column and building a type object out of it, but as I said, we don't want to use a model/type for the data as we want to keep it flexible.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I have the feeling I seem to overlook something simple.

Comment: Isn't possible for you to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result)`?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are using the non-typed `Query` API, each returned row is also an `IDictionary<string,object>` (in addition to the `dynamic` API), which usually works fine with `JsonConvert`; for example, the following works OK for me:

```cs
var tables = (from row in await conn.QueryAsync("select top 5 * from sys.tables")
              select (IDictionary<string, object>)row).AsList();
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tables, Formatting.Indented);
System.Console.WriteLine(json);
```

outputting:

```
[
  {
    "name": "spt_fallback_db",
    "object_id": 117575457,
    "principal_id": null,
    "schema_id": 1,
    "parent_object_id": 0,
    "type": "U ",
    "type_desc": "USER_TABLE",
    "create_date": "2003-04-08T09:18:01.557",
    "modify_date": "2017-08-22T19:40:40.763",
    "is_ms_shipped": true,
    "is_published": false,
    "is_schema_published": false,
    "lob_data_space_id": 0,
    "filestream_data_space_id": null,
    "max_column_id_used": 8,
  ... etc
```

Comment: Your query output was exactly the same as my output, so that wasn't the issue. Apparently the only change I had to make was to add the _AsList()_ to the query for it to work properly. 
So I was right in that it was something simple - thanks for helping me figuring it out!